# Node - Array not emptying

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm with a scraping project.

When I **scrape** from a site all the data goes to a `JSON`, the problem is when I **scrape** another info the `JSON` contains the old info + the new one. At the begining I set a `data = []`, but is not working.

```
app.post('/scraping', function(req, res) {

    (async () => {

        try {

            data = [];

            response = await requestPromise(req.body);
            $ = cheerio.load(response);
    
            $('div#all > img').each(function() {
                let img = $(this).attr('data-src');
                imgs.push({
                    imgURL: img
                });
            });

            data = JSON.stringify(imgs);
            fs.writeFileSync('chapter.json', data);
            res.redirect('/scraping');

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    
    })();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `data` variable is a global, or defined somewhere out of scope. That means that the `data` "reference" is the same between all calls.

Declare `data` within your function, i.e. `let data = [];`.